# JavaScript Recursive Callback Function - ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, jquery-callback

My idea is to show all images in the array. At first the Noise image is getting hidden after this it calls the showArray() function to show the images in the Array.

```
Trial = (function() {
  function Trial(imageArray) {
    this._images = new Array();
    this._images = imageArray;
  }

  Trial.prototype.startTrial = function() {
    return $("#noise").hide(0, showImages());
  };

  Trial.prototype.showImages = function() {
    var imageToShow;
    imageToShow = this._images.pop();
    if (imageToShow === void 0) {
      $("#noise").show;
      return;
    }
    $("#img").attr("src", imageToShow.src);
    return $("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(0, showImages());
  };

  return Trial;

})();

image1 = new AMPImage("someImage1.png", 500);  //imagePath, delay in ms
image2 = new AMPImage("someImage2.png", 750);
image3 = new AMPImage("someImage3.png", 1000);

myImageArray = [image1, image2, image3];
trial1 = new Trial(myImageArray);
trial1.startTrial();
```

But on executing startTrial()  I get the error message

> ReferenceError: showArray is not defined

Comment: Well? Where is the showArray function? Is it defined?

Comment: oh it was an typo after testing different things. I correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest edit:

The context doesn't work quite like that.  i.e. `showImages` isn't a variable.  It's a method on the prototype of the `Trial` class.  If you want to call it from external code you can do:

```
myTrial.showImages();
```

If you want to call it from another method within the `Trial` class, you have to call it as a method on the current instance.  You can get a reference to the current instance as `this`.  i.e.

```
this.showImages();
```

instead of

```
showImages();
```

What you actually want to do is not call the function immediately though, you want the function to be called once the animation finishes.  To do this you pass the function as a value to the animation method.  Just omit the `()` and you will pass the function.

The problem with this is that the `this` context is a fickle beast, and will not be correct if you do that.  To maintain the correct `this` context you must bind it:

```
var showImagesToCallLater = this.showImages.bind(this);

// some time later, perhaps inside another method you can then do:

showImagesToCallLater();

// and this will have the correct `this` context.
```

So for our example we want `.hide(0, this.showImages.bind(this));` and `.fadeOut(0, this.showImages.bind(this));`

### Additional Code Review

I've reviewed the rest of your code, suggesting additional changes you might like to make.  If you just want to get the code working as quickly as possible, you can probably ignore this:

```
// There's no need to create an extra closure here,
// we can remove a level of nesting.
function Trial(imageArray) {
  // There's no point writing to `this._images` then immediately
  // overwriting, so we only write to it once here
  this._images = imageArray;
}

Trial.prototype.startTrial = function() {
  // I assume you want to begin showing images once #noise is hidden.
  // To do this, pass a function to hide.
  return $("#noise").hide(0, this.showImages.bind(this));
};

Trial.prototype.showImages = function () {
  var imageToShow;
  imageToShow = this._images.pop();
  if (imageToShow === void 0) {
    // You need to actually call this function
    $("#noise").show();
    return;
  }
  $("#img").attr("src", imageToShow.src);
  // Once one image has been shown, I'm guessing you want to show the next.
  // to do this, we `.bind` the function so it has the correct `this` value.
  return $("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay)
                  .fadeOut(0, this.showImages.bind(this));
};

image1 = new AMPImage("someImage1.png", 500);  //imagePath, delay in ms
image2 = new AMPImage("someImage2.png", 750);
image3 = new AMPImage("someImage3.png", 1000);

myImageArray = [image1, image2, image3];
trial1 = new Trial(myImageArray);
trial1.startTrial();
```

Rather than calling the function, which will make it execute immediately, you want it to execute when the animation has finished.  To do this, you need to pass the actual function, so call `.bind(this)` on the function.  That way it will execute in the correct context.

You could alternatively build a more "functional" version of this as:

```
function startTrial(imageArray) {
  // note how we pass the function showImage, we don't call it
  $("#noise").hide(0, showImage);
  function showImage() {
    var imageToShow = imageArray.pop();
    if (imageToShow === undefined) {
      $("#noise").show();
      return;
    }
    $("#img").attr("src", imageToShow.src);
    return $("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(0, showImage);
  }
}
var image1 = new AMPImage("someImage1.png", 500);  //imagePath, delay in ms
var image2 = new AMPImage("someImage2.png", 750);
var image3 = new AMPImage("someImage3.png", 1000);

var myImageArray = [image1, image2, image3];
startTrial(myImageArray);
```

Which style you prefer is very much up to personal taste.  The functional version lets you forget about all the strange `this` binding behavior.

Comment: with your changes the recursion works.
but a new problem has come up. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197553/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-callbacks-work-not-as-expected-after-rewriting-c

Comment: You need to read my code more carefully, note that I do `fn.bind(this)` not `fn()`.  You are calling the function, which makes it execute immediately, you have to pass the actual function as a value to have it be called as a callback.

Comment: how to pass the variable `imageArray` to the function call?


`fn(imageArray).bind(this);` does not work.

Comment: You can just do `fn.bind(this, imageArray)` or you can do `function () { this.fn(imageArray) }.bind(this)`

Comment: You probably shouldn't need to do that though.  If you use the prototype/class based solution as in your question you can just get `this.imageArray` inside the function, no need to pass it as an argument.