# jQuery .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() Callbacks work not as expected after rewriting code to recursive callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, delay

The rewritten code should display any amount of pictures and the old code is static.
But what the new code does is to show instantly the last image of the array and for the full delay of all images together therefore 30 seconds.

My old code looks like this and worked well with the jquery callbacks.
http://pastebin.com/XH2aRqBh

The rewritten code:

```
//Class Trial
Trial = (function() {
  function Trial(imageArray) {
    this.images = imageArray;
  }

  Trial.prototype.startTrial = function() {
    $("#noise").hide(0, this.showImages(this.images));  
  };

  Trial.prototype.showImages = function(imageArray) {
    imageToShow = imageArray.pop();  
    if(imageToShow === undefined){
      $("#noise").show(0);
      console.log("show noise");
      return;
    }
    console.log("pop image : ", imageToShow.image.src, " delay : ", imageToShow.delay);
    $("#img").show();
    $("#img").attr("src", imageToShow.image.src);
    $("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(0, this.showImages(imageArray));
  };

  return Trial;

})();

//create objects and run a Trial
  image0 = new AMPImage("img/image0.jpg", 10000);
  image1 = new AMPImage("img/image1.jpg", 500);
  image2 = new AMPImage("img/image2.jpg", 100);
  image3 = new AMPImage("img/image3.jpg", 10);
  image4 = new AMPImage("img/image4.jpg", 500);
  image5 = new AMPImage("img/image5.jpg", 100);
  image6 = new AMPImage("img/image6.jpg", 10000);
  myImageArray = [image6, image5, image4, image3, image2, image1, image0];
  trial1 = new Trial(myImageArray);
  trial1.startTrial(myImageArray);
```

And the HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="flick">

    <img id="noise" src="noise2d.png" style="display: ; height: 400px; width: 400px;" class="flickImg">

    <img id="img" src="" style="display: none ; height: 400px; width: 400px;"     class="flickImg">


</div>

</body>
<script src="snippet.js"></script>
</html>
```

The JavaScript Console Output:

```
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image0.jpg  delay :  10000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image1.jpg  delay :  2000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image2.jpg  delay :  2000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image3.jpg  delay :  2000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image4.jpg  delay :  2000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image5.jpg  delay :  2000 snippet.js:41
pop image :  file:/// ... /img/image6.jpg  delay :  10000 snippet.js:41
show noise snippet.js:38
undefined
```

Comment: I find the use of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` with duration `0` a little bit confusing. Have you tried removing `("#img").show();` and passing `imageToShow.delay` directly to `fadeIn` like this: `$("#img").fadeIn(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(imageToShow.delay, this.showImages(imageArray));`?

Comment: if I use your line instead, the last image in the array is slowly (~10sec) fade in and fade out. But the others are not shown.
the fadeIn(0) and fadeOut(0) worked well in my old code.
Maybe something with the recursion is wrong?  the console outputs the "console.log()" comments instantly. it doesen't look like the jquery callbacks wait until the animation is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pass a function in this line. You actually call `this.showImages`:

```
$("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(0, this.showImages(imageArray));
```

You need to pass an anonymous function, which when called executes `this.showImages`:

```
var self = this;
$("#img").fadeIn(0).delay(imageToShow.delay).fadeOut(0, function() {
    self.showImages(imageArray);
});
```

And I think you also need to remove the line `$("#img").show();`.

Comment: thank you Jan and ForbesLindesay. 
with the code above it works :)